# Why CentOS converts ATA bus to scsi bus?

Tags: centos, qemu

I use libvirt + qemu to boot a VM with a disk with IDE bus

device in libvirt:

```
<disk type='network' device='disk'>
  <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none' io='native'/>
  <source protocol='iscsi' name='xxx'>
    <host name='127.0.0.1' port='xxx'/>
  </source>
  <target dev='hdb' bus='ide'/>
  <boot order='3'/>
  <alias name='ide0-0-1'/>
  <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='1'/>
</disk>
```

in qemu:

```
-drive file.driver=iscsi,file.portal=127.0.0.1:xxx,file.target=xxx,file.lun=xxx,file.transport=tcp,format=raw,if=none,id=drive-ide0-0-1,cache=none,aio=native
-device ide-hd,bus=ide.0,unit=1,drive=drive-ide0-0-1,id=ide0-0-1,bootindex=3,write-cache=on
```

Guest OS is CentOS-7.9-x86_64-DVD-2009

After booting, the display in dmesg shows

```
May 18 06:07:37 localhost kernel: ata1: PATA max MWDMA2 cmd 0x1f0 ctl 0x3f6 bmdma 0xd120 irq 14
May 18 06:07:37 localhost kernel: ata2: PATA max MWDMA2 cmd 0x170 ctl 0x376 bmdma 0xd128 irq 15
May 18 09:15:54 localhost kernel: ata1.00: ATAPI: QEMU DVD-ROM, 2.5+, max UDMA/100
May 18 09:15:54 localhost kernel: ata1.01: ATA-7: QEMU HARDDISK, 2.5+, max UDMA/100
May 18 09:15:54 localhost kernel: ata1.01: 6291456 sectors, multi 16: LBA48
May 18 09:15:54 localhost kernel: ata1.00: configured for MWDMA2
May 18 09:15:54 localhost kernel: ata1.01: configured for MWDMA2
May 18 09:15:54 localhost kernel: scsi 0:0:0:0: CD-ROM            QEMU     QEMU DVD-ROM     2.5+ PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
May 18 09:15:54 localhost kernel: scsi 0:0:1:0: Direct-Access     ATA      QEMU HARDDISK    2.5+ PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
May 18 09:15:54 localhost kernel: sr 0:0:0:0: [sr0] scsi3-mmc drive: 4x/4x cd/rw xa/form2 tray
May 18 09:15:54 localhost kernel: cdrom: Uniform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20
May 18 09:15:54 localhost kernel: sd 0:0:1:0: [sda] 6291456 512-byte logical blocks: (3.22 GB/3.00 GiB)
May 18 09:15:54 localhost kernel: sd 0:0:1:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
May 18 09:15:54 localhost kernel: sd 0:0:1:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
May 18 09:15:54 localhost kernel: sd 0:0:1:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
```

and shows in lshw

```
[root@localhost ~]# lshw -class disk
  *-cdrom                   
       description: DVD reader
       product: QEMU DVD-ROM
       vendor: QEMU
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/cdrom
       logical name: /dev/sr0
       version: 2.5+
       capabilities: removable audio dvd
       configuration: ansiversion=5 status=ready
     *-medium
          physical id: 0
          logical name: /dev/cdrom
          capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
          configuration: signature=6b8b4567
  *-disk
       description: ATA Disk
       product: QEMU HARDDISK
       physical id: 0.1.0
       bus info: scsi@0:0.1.0
       logical name: /dev/sda
       version: 2.5+
       serial: 918a6997-1928-38a1-9
       size: 3GiB (3221MB)
       configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
```

Why does CentOS convert the ATA bus to an scsi bus? Where can I see a more relevant description?

Comment: Generalization: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCSI_/_ATA_Translation. Also see https://www.t10.org/drafts.htm#SAT https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/ata/libata-scsi.c

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how the Linux kernel handles Parallel ATA (IDE) and Serial ATA (SATA). Initially, there was a set of IDE-specific drivers, and IDE drives appeared as `hda` etc. But when Serial ATA came on the scene, Jeff Garzik decided to use the existing SCSI [midlayer](https://lwn.net/Articles/336262/) in the kernel; he [gave a number of reasons](https://lwn.net/Articles/33624/), notably:

> - Many of the advantages are derived the existence of the scsi   mid-layer.  It does a lot of work on our behalf, allowing me   to
>   focus on the ATA command protocols (PIO-in, PIO-out, DMA,   etc.)
>   almost exclusively.
>
> […]
>
> - Serial ATA is looming quickly on the horizon.  Both device and host   controller SATA implementations really lend themselves to behaviors
>   that have existed in SCSI for a while.  SATA even defines use of SCSI
>   Enclosure Services.
> - The Linux SCSI layer handles hotplugging, and is more modular.   It already has refcounted devices and sysfs and such.  Creating a   new
>   block device driver from scratch means handling all those   little
>   details.
> - SCSI has been doing basic error recovery and queue control for a   while now.  Upcoming SATA2 will benefit greatly from this, as well
>   ATA TCQ if I ever get around to implementing the latter.
> - ATAPI is SCSI-like.

The result was `libata`, which provides support for ATA devices and presents them through the SCSI midlayer, as SCSI drives. Initially this covered SATA devices and a few Intel PATA controllers (although as far as I remember the old IDE device drivers were still used by default for the latter).

A few years later, [libata was extended to support most PATA controllers](https://lwn.net/Articles/198344/) and the majority of IDE devices [ended up being handled as SCSI devices](https://lwn.net/Articles/360347/). The legacy IDE drivers [were removed in 2021](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=b7fb14d3ac63).